# Background Fetch every 15 seconds isn't working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, fetch

I'm new in `iOS` background fetch but in application I must develop now my client wants to obtain some data from special device (temeprature sensor) every 15 seconds (sic!) as long as application runs. Device don't know anything about me and I must refresh it's state. I know it's lame but it is the only way. I've enabled `Background Fetch` in `Capabilities` tab and   implemented all methods I need. When I use `Debug -> Simulate Background Fetch` it is working, but when I want to test my app in real device, disconnected from Mac I don't have any notification or log (I make them when I want obtain data from web for debug simplicity). Why isn't it working? Here is `AppDelegate.m` code I use:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage new]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage new]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:2.0];


    return YES;
}



-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Dzwoni ci dzownek!";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    // All network connectionds here...

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: This is a terrible idea, you should use a silent push notification to tel the app to update and only send out the push notification when there really is data to update. The way you are trying it will drain the battery very vast and result in a bad user experience.

Comment: I can't. It is not fetching data from web but from special device for example temperature sensor, motion sensor. I can ask this device for it's state but device don't know nothing about me and cannot push any data at all. Client wants to do this every 15 seconds so I thought I can do it this way but it is not called. I've updated my question for better understanding.

Comment: Well this complicates things. The background refresh is called depending on the user needs and the system decides if and when to call the background fetch of you app. This is issue 1, if you app is request the refresh to often and taking to long iOS will stop refreshing you app.

Comment: Also be aware that 15sec might to often, use `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` to set the fetch time to the system minimum.

Comment: I am aware of all those things. The problem is it never refreshs. Even with `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` I never see any log.